# Is this proof circular? (Proof that the open disk/ball of radius 'r' is an open set)

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

[image: Proof that the Open Disk is about a point, x, is an open set]

This is on page 109 of "Vector Calculus" (5th ed.) by Marsden and Tromba. Here's my problem with this proof: We're trying to prove that an Open Disk is, in fact, an open set, but when we use the triangle inequality, this assumption is made:

$||y - x|| + ||x-x_0|| < s + ||x-x_0||$ which implies $||y - x|| < s$—but we can only make this assumption if we know $D_s(x)$ is an open set. We can't know that $D_s(x)$ is an open set because we don't know that the open disks are open sets yet.

Isn't proving the open disk, $D_r(x_0)$, is an open set by assuming $D_s(y)$ is an open set just assuming what we're trying to prove (with different variables)? Or is there some kind of implied recursive/induction-like logic going on?

Comment: No, in that line, you are merely using the definition of a disk. It would be a circular argument if you the proof something along the lines of "$y$ has a disk centered at it such that it lies completely in $D_s(y)$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't say that $\|y-x\|<s$ because $D_s(x)$ is an open set; we say that because $D_s(x)$ is defined to be the set of all points $y$ for which $\|y-x\|<s$.  There is no circular logic here.

Comment: Ah; it's that simple. Is this question one simply solved enough that I should delete it?

Comment: There's no reason to do so.  Who knows, it might be helpful to someone.